# Convert <img> tags for <amp-img> tags in wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm learning PHP and creating a template for Wordpress and I'm watching tutorials on YouTube, I ended up finding this tutorial here: [encurtador.com.br/dHN57](http://encurtador.com.br/dHN57)

I saw that you could create an AMP version in the template, basically the guy in the tutorial makes a filter where he takes everything from the post and plays it to an amp-single.php file with the AMP HTML version, the github link for his project is right here: [encurtador.com.br/fvCEI](http://encurtador.com.br/fvCEI)

The part of the code that matters is this:

```
$allowed_html = array(

 'img' => array(
      'src' => true,
      'srcset' => true,
      'width' => true,
      'height' => true,
      'layout' => true,
      'alt' => true
    ),
```

That basically he filters the post's img tags and plays for the AMP version, I added a few more things because he doesn't talk about the video, which in this case has to convert the tags to, and I'm having a problem, I don't know how I take the src (link) of the image and set it to a variable, so that I can get the size of the image with PHP's getimagesize and put it in the tag, I'll put the code below for you to understand better:

I created a variable named **$tamanho** ("Tamanho" is size in English) :

`$tamanho = getimagesize(PRECISO COLOCAR O LINK DAS IMAGENS AQUI);`

Then I throw this information into the tag's width and height attributes:

```
$amp_content = preg_replace('/(<img[^>]+>(?:<\/img>)?)/i', '$1</amp-img>', $html_content_filtered);

$amp_content = str_replace('<img', '<amp-img " width="'. $tamanho[0] .'" height="' . $tamanho[1] . '" layout="responsive"', $amp_content);
```

I was wondering how I could get the link to the images and automatically play in the size variable?

I already tested by placing the link of any image and it worked:

```
$tamanho = getimagesize("http://localhost/apostolado/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/teste.png");
```

In this case, I want to get the src value of every image I have in the post.

I've tried to take the $ allowed_html variable and put it directly into getimagesize, like this:

```
$tamanho = getimagesize ($allowed_html['img']['src']);
```

But wordpress is not returning with the image link, I even made an echo to see what it is returning and gives only the number 1, in place of the link appears the number 1.

Is there some kind of wordpress call that I can get the image link from inside the post?

Comment: Instead of URL shorteners, can you post the final links?

Comment: If you are working with WordPress, I would recommend using as many WordPress functions as possible. For instance, there is a function called [`wp_get_attachment_metadata`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_metadata/) that will give you a bunch of information on a single image, as long as you know the image's ID.